# Mustache and Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, haml, mustache

I have got this haml/mustache template:

```
{{#data}}
  ok
  {{#items}}
    {{#item}}
      %b ID: {{id}}
    {{/item}}
  {{/items}}
{{/data}}
```

And I have got `Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal` Error.

I render it in Sinatra

```
Mustache.render(haml(:index), hash)
```

Comment: I'm confused about your haml. What do the {{ mean?

Comment: it is mustache :) http://mustache.github.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about rendering with Sinatra, but with this command:

```
cat example.yml foo.haml.mustache | mustache | haml -e
```

this data file `example.yml`

```
---
data:
  - items:
    - item:
      - id: 1
      - id: 2
      - id: 3
---
```

and template (foo.haml.mustache ):

```
{{#data}}
#ok
{{#items}}
{{#item}}
  %b ID: {{id}}
{{/item}}
{{/items}}
{{/data}}
```

I get following result:

```
<div id='ok'>
  <b>ID: 1</b>
  <b>ID: 2</b>
  <b>ID: 3</b>
</div>
```

Pls pay attention to indentation level in *.mustache file. Hope this help you.

Comment: Yep, I understand, that I can remove all indents (tabs) so it will work fine. But it is horrible reading: mustache without tabs :) so actual problem is ho to make haml work with mustache and its indenting