# Sharing templates beetween JS and Rails using Haml + Mustache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml, mustache

I am trying to make common templates that used both by Rails and the client side, ie in coffescript.

I use [hogan_assets](https://github.com/infbio/haml_assets) and [haml_assets](https://github.com/leshill/hogan_assets) to export templates to JS. However I can't find a way to use HAML and Mustache to render server-side views.

Partial solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215103/mustache-and-haml), but it doesn't work with view helpers, ie, "render partial" doesn't work.

For some unknown reason chaining of handlers, such as .mustache.haml, doesn't work, and I can't find neither good info on Rails template handler nor an example on how to build "chainable" handler.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experimenting with something like [smt_rails](http://railsware.com/blog/2012/04/12/shared-mustache-templates-for-rails-3/) lately, but I have yet to find a silver bullet.

Comment: I have tried that, the problem is that I couldn't make it work with HAML. I am thinking of build my own solution, as far as I see it would be very useful.

Comment: For HAML, there are some libraries that can handle it. Try checking out [Stache](https://github.com/agoragames/stache/pull/10). There is also a branch of the [mustache_rails3](https://github.com/mikesmullin/mustache_rails3) library.

Comment: I still can't believe that no best practice/major library came out to do this, as many web services must need it now!