# How to keep HAML from reordering words in the class attribute?

Tags: haml, mustache, ractivejs

HAML and ractive.js seem to play well together (if you don't mind [not indenting the contents of a mustache section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215103/mustache-and-haml)), though I have found one problem I can't solve.

When I do this:

```
.like{ class: "{{#if like}}active{{/if}}" }
  ...
```

I get this:

```
<div class='like like}}active{{/if}} {{#if'>...</div>
```

It appears that the HAML parser is assuming that word order doesn't matter inside of a class declaration, and is messing with my string (though I can't imagine why), but in this case I need that string to be preserved!

I know I could use plain html, but it gets quite messy when there are many nested tags.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

If I change it from this:

```
.like{ class: "{{#if like}}active{{/if}}" }
```

to this:

```
%div{ class: "like{{#if like}} active{{/if}}" }
```

It works fine.